# Mule 3 convert a json object in to an array

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mel

I have the below dynamic response coming from third party API, now I need to transform only the particular JSON object ("MyValues") into an array.

The payload here is sample is is very large .

Current Output:

```
{
    "Body": {
          "Status": "200",
          "Result": {
            "MyValues":{
                "Name":"ABC TEST",
                "Phone":"1234"
            }
          }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "Body": {
          "Status": "200",
          "Result": {
            "MyValues":[{
                "Name":"ABC TEST",
                "Phone":"1234"
            }]
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a single level nested object ? MyValues that is . Can you paste a bit more in the sample input ?

Comment: No it can be multiple like sometime it shows one record sometimes it shows 3 4 or more than that, so if it is more then one then the [] sign is coming but i need to make both response consistent.

Comment: For more than one it is coming 
"MyValues":[{
                "Name":"ABC TEST",
                "Phone":"1234"
            },
   {
                "Name":"ABC TEST2",
                "Phone":"12345"
            }]
the above is perfectly fine. Now i want for even one record it should be in array as to make both consistent. @SalimKhan

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matching based on the type received, array or object. I created a recursive function to find the instances of a key name and perform the change in a generic way.

Example:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%function convertToSingleArray(x, key)
    x match {
                  // OPTIONAL :array  ->  x map convertToSingleArray($, key),
                  :object ->  x mapObject {($$): [$] when ( (($$ as :string) == key) and ((typeOf $) as :string  == ":object")) otherwise convertToSingleArray($, key)
                  },
                  default  ->  x
            }
---
convertToSingleArray(payload, "MyValues")
```

Comment: I don't want to define the response here in DW as the response i give is an example the actual response is very big and i can not define it. I need such a function that will read the response and if fine MyValues as a JSON Object then make it an array else nothing to do .@aled

Comment: Thanks your solution also worked, well I wrote one solution short and simple and working also too.  
payload - "MyValues" ++ { "MyValues":[payload.MyValues]}  when MyValues.Result.MyValues is :object  
  otherwise  payload

Comment: Note that your solution will only work for a given structure of the payload.